# No image in html report output generated with DynamicJasper API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I'm building a report with *DynamicJasper API* and I want to insert an image in a column.

I have:

```java
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
drb.addImageColumn("Image", "image", "java.awt.Image", 500,false, ImageScaleMode.NO_RESIZE, detailStyle);
```

And the property for "image" is built from an URL:

```java
Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(pathToImage));
```

The problem I'm having is the image displays in *PDF* output but not in *HTML* output. Inspecting the generated source, I see the following:

```html
<img src="nullimg_0_0_16" style="height: 50px" alt="">
```

Comment: You can try this way: the sample [ImageExpressionColumnReportTest](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/ImageExpressionColumnReportTest.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex K but that didn't work for HTML output.

One needs to use jasper's ImageServlet. The solution is documented here:

http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-export-to-html/